# Add a node before a closing tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

What's the best way to insert an element into a page's HEAD directly *before* the closing  tag using JavaScript?

```
...<HEAD>
<script>...</script>
<script>...</script>
<script>...</script>
<link .../>
<link .../>
<link title="MY NEW LINK ELEMENT" />
</HEAD>...
```

I know about the ol' `insertBefore(sp1, sp2.nextSibling)` trick, but that just lets you drop something *after* a closing tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're doing straight JavaScript, it's called [`appendChild`](http://www.w3schools.com/DOM/met_element_appendchild.asp). jQuery has a wrapper called [`append`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/append#content). Prototype has [`insert`](http://prototypejs.org/api/element/insert) which appends when not given a location.

Comment: Oh... um... DUH!... jeeze. I need to take a break I think. 

Out of curiosity, how would you insert directly after the open tag then?

Comment: @MrSparky parentElement.insertBefore(newElement, parentElement.firstChild)